# eclipse: no warning for unused private methods

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings, eclipse-kepler

Regarding eclipse Kepler SR1

Hi,

I remember that a unused private methods were getting a warning from the compiler.

I don't know if it's changed switching to Kepler (or a previous release) or if it is project settings, because I'm working on a new project where the eclipse settings are shared.

I even couldn't find the setting in the eclipse compiler settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to your project on "Package Explorer", right-click on it and choose "properties". Then inside properties "Java Compiler", "Errors/Warnings". Check the box with "Enable project specific settings". Scroll down to the section where it says "Unnecessary code" and check them to "Warning"

Comment: There are project specific settings (shared using version control system), where many things are ignored. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

The setting is `Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Unnecessary code > Unused private member`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

```
Windows --> Preferences --> Java --> Compiler --> Errors/Warnings
```

Under `Unnecessary Code` section you can find `Unused private member`

Change it to `Warning`

Answer (score 0):

It could be your company/ project uses other eclipse plugins which allow code analysis with lets say sonar and the eclipse static code analysis thatfore has been fully disabled.

I am still using the Indigo version of eclipse but i assume you can see what youre looking for under Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings

Comment: Ah i was too slow, see, accept and upvote answer of User Sandhu ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change settings from preferences. Here is some illustration.[image: Warning_error]